# Benford's Law number generator inequality

Tags: python

I created a small Python program that will calculate the probability of various 'random' numbers and see if they follow  Benford's Law .

My algorithms may not be the most efficient for this, but it still does the job.

My question is, why does numGen1 not follow the rule, where as numGen2 and numGen3 follow the rule?

Is it something to do with the way that computers generate numbers?

Sample Output (with n = 5000):

NumGen1:

```
Occurance of starting with 1 is 0.112 
Occurance of starting with 2 is 0.104 
Occurance of starting with 3 is 0.117 
Occurance of starting with 4 is 0.117
```

NumGen2:

```
Occurance of starting with 1 is 0.327 
Occurance of starting with 2 is 0.208 
Occurance of starting with 3 is 0.141 
Occurance of starting with 4 is 0.078
```

NumGen3:

```
Occurance of starting with 1 is 0.301 
Occurance of starting with 2 is 0.176 
Occurance of starting with 3 is 0.125 
Occurance of starting with 4 is 0.097
```

Here is my code:

```
import random
def numGen1(n):
    '''random.randint choses an integer from [1,n]'''
    L = []
    start1 = 0
    start2 = 0
    start3 = 0
    start4 = 0

    for i in range(n):
        L.append(str(random.randint(1,10000000)))

    for numbers in L:
        x = eval(numbers[0])

        if x == 1:
            start1 += 1
        if x == 2:
            start2 += 1
        if x == 3:
            start3 += 1
        if x == 4:
            start4 += 1

    print ("Occurance of starting with 1 is %.3f \n"
           "Occurance of starting with 2 is %.3f \n"
           "Occurance of starting with 3 is %.3f \n"
           "Occurance of starting with 4 is %.3f ") % (start1/float(n),start2/float(n),start3/float(n),start4/float(n))


def numGen2(n):
    '''random.random() takes a number x, such that 0 <= x < 1 '''
    L = []
    start1 = 0
    start2 = 0
    start3 = 0
    start4 = 0


    for i in range(n):
        L.append(str(random.random()*i))


    for numbers in L:
        x = eval(numbers[0])

        if x == 1:
            start1 += 1
        if x == 2:
            start2 += 1
        if x == 3:
            start3 += 1
        if x == 4:
            start4 += 1


    print ("Occurance of starting with 1 is %.3f \n"
           "Occurance of starting with 2 is %.3f \n"
           "Occurance of starting with 3 is %.3f \n"
           "Occurance of starting with 4 is %.3f ") % (start1/float(n),start2/float(n),start3/float(n),start4/float(n))



def numGen3(n):
    '''Fibonnaci sequence generator'''
    a = 0
    b = 1
    c = 0

    L=[]
    start1 = 0
    start2 = 0
    start3 = 0
    start4 = 0

    for i in range(n):
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        L.append(str(c))

    for numbers in L:
        x = eval(numbers[0])

        if x == 1:
            start1 += 1
        if x == 2:
            start2 += 1
        if x == 3:
            start3 += 1
        if x == 4:
            start4 += 1


    print ("Occurance of starting with 1 is %.3f \n"
           "Occurance of starting with 2 is %.3f \n"
           "Occurance of starting with 3 is %.3f \n"
           "Occurance of starting with 4 is %.3f ") % (start1/float(n),start2/float(n),start3/float(n),start4/float(n))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're mixing things up here.

Bendford's law applies to sources of data, and you can say it's something they adhere to. You have essentially defined three random number generators; which have their own rules governing how they create the numbers.

There are many types of random number generation, with the two main ones being *uniform*, and *Gaussian*, where they generate numbers *uniformly* spaced between the minimum and maximum, and distributed normally about a mean with a stdard deviation (respectively).

Only your third random number generator can be said to satisfy Benford's law, the second is *similar*, but it does not obey the law  (it does not match log(d+1) - log(d)). These are just characteristics of your random number generators, it's a maths thing.

Your third one obeys the law since the Fibonacci numbers obey the rule. You would get the same result if you did the same with factorials, and the powers of most numbers, as they happen to obey Benford's law.

The second PRNG is dependant on N, for example, if N is some value like 80000, then you will miss out on the 8XXXX and 9XXXX entries, and skew the results. Presumably the best bet is to only have N as powers of 10, i will test this. How this behaves for N = \infty though i'm not sure either, i'll try and extrapolate.

Here is a plot of the distribution for different values of N, note the cusps, and how they appear for different colours (sorry about the legend, i wasn't thinking when i plotted it, and it tooko a fair while to plot.)

[image]

If you only look at powers of ten, then you lose the cusps;

[image]

I ran each value of N enough times so that they all have the same number of samples - i.e. the line for 1000 was run 1000 times, and the line for 1000000 was run once. That should have removed most of the randomness. I would say this is not following Benford's law. There might be some magic number you can select to get it to work, but that's not really in the spirit of Benford's law, which is normally taken to be the behaviour in the limit of all of the data.

There's a chance that as N increases further, it shifts towards the correct distribution, i'll think up an analytic formula for it and then try and plot that.

As for unutbu's comment about Benford distributions absorbing the properties of other distributions, I think that's a bit of a confusion. If you *uniformly randomly select values from another distribution* - which is what this code is doing - then you will end up with the original distribution again. In this vein, if you uniformly randomly select variables from *any* other distribution, you will recover the original distribution as your sample size grows.

I completely agree that taking numbers uniformly (i.e. ala `random.random()`) will give back a Benford distribution, *if the original set of numbers follows Benford's law*, so the problem boils down to deciding if then average of the probabilities of numbers starting with each digit in each of the sets:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
...
```

has a Benford distribution. The thing to notice here, is that at each multiple of 10, the distribution is equal for all numbers, it is uneven for non multiples of ten, giving more bias to earlier numbers in the sequence. Whether or not the amount of additional bias given to the numbers follows Benford's law though, i do not know.

This plot from wikipedia:

[image]

Claims that it does, but does not offer anything other than that.

The probability for each number being included in any sample is:

[image]

Where N is the maximum (or in the original question, `n` in the function call), and `i` is the number.

That then needs to be converted to give the probability of the number having `X` as it's first digit. I'm not sure how to do that in some easy way yet, will take a bit more digging. I'll call it B(i) for now though, where if something is truely benfordly distributed, it has B(1) = 30.1% (etc.)

I can plot it though; Here it is for N=100:

[image]

At every power of ten, there is a ripple like feature, which spreads out to the next power of ten, which you can easily relate to an increased probability of numbers starting with X (i.e. 
for N=119, B(i) will be higher than for N=99, since we have had 20 extra iterations through the loop, wherein there are an increased number of numbers starting with 1, i.e. all of the extra ones)

Each of the ripples is longer, as it is spread out across the whole of the domain 10^m -> 10^{m+1}. Here it is for N=1000

[image]

And here's B_i(N) for each `i`. I'll add plots with larger N as i create them. These plots are every `[i * 10 ** j for j in range(lowPower, highPower) for i in range(1,10)] + [10 ** (highPower)]`, with cubic spline interpolation, so that i didn't have to do as many data points. The interpolation makes very little difference though.

[image]

it makes a little more sense to view it on a log scale though;

[image]

Note that you don't have to average these lines to get the average of the whole distribution, these are the expected values for B_i(N) for the second PRNG in the question.

Comment: @will: Can you explain how you know `i*random.random()` (used in numGen2) does not follow Benford's law?

Comment: @unutbu added a bit more info on `i*random.random()`.

Comment: @will, thanks for looking into this. According to [Terry Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/benfords-law-zipfs-law-and-the-pareto-distribution/), about 40% of the way down, if `N` obeys Benford's law, then a random number picked from 1 to N also obeys Benford's law. If I'm understanding this correctly, this means if we pick N not equal to powers of 10 but instead from a Benford distribution, then the `i` in `i*random.random()` will be Benford distributed. Tao also says the Benford distribution has an absorptive property which would make `i*random.random()` Benford distributed.

Comment: Hold on -- "If you multiply any distribution by another uniform distribution, then the initial one will still stand," -- the product of two uniform distributions is not uniform...

Comment: @unutbu Not sure what made me say that, it was madness.

Comment: @unutbu - I've changed it now. What i really meant was that if you select numbers uniformly randomly from another distribution, you are just sampling that distribution, and so eventually you will recover it.