# Matplotlib changing scale to log changes line colours

Tags: python, matplotlib

Pretty self explanatory, in my [answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26690472/432913), when i put the x axis to log scale, the colours of the lines changes.

After a bit of further investigation, it only happens on one system i'm using, and not others.

It happens on Scientific Linux 6.4, with matplotlib version 1.2.0. It works as expected on Mint Linux using the MATE desktop and matplotlib version 1.1.1rc.

After creating a plot and showing it, it appears fine. But if i click to change the scale to log (on either x or y) it alters the colours.

Colours are fine here:
[image]

But then after changing it, they are altered.
[image]

Any idea why this is happening, or how to prevent it?

It happens with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from math import floor, log10
import cProfile
import sys
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate


def digit(number):
  if number >= 10000:
    return int(floor(number / 10000))
  if number >= 1000:
    return int(floor(number / 1000))
  elif number >= 100:
    return int(floor(number / 100))
  elif number >= 10:
    return int(floor(number / 10))
  else:
    return number

def digit2(number):
  return int(str(number)[0])


def calcProbs(startingN = 10, maxN = 100, logScale = True, interp = False):


  if logScale:
    lowPower, highPower = int(floor(log10(startingN))), int(floor(log10(maxN)))
    Ns = [i * 10 ** j for j in range(lowPower, highPower) for i in range(1,10)] + [10 ** (highPower)]
    probs = [[0 for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(len(Ns))]
  else:
    Ns = range(startingN, maxN+1)
    probs = [[0 for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(maxN-startingN+1)]

  for N, prob in zip(Ns, probs):
    print N, prob

  for index, N in enumerate(Ns):
    print N
    for n in range(1,N+1):
      for i in range(1, n+1):
        probs[index][digit(i)-1] += 1.0 / (N  * n) 

    probs[index][9] = sum(probs[index][:-1]) #Make sure always sums to 1.

  probs = zip(*probs)

  if interp:
    newNs = range(min(Ns), max(Ns))
    for i, prob in enumerate(probs):
      probs[i] = interpolate.splev(newNs, interpolate.splrep(Ns, prob,s=0), der=0)

    Ns = newNs

  return Ns, probs

"""
cProfile.run("calcProbs(maxN=500)")

"""
Ns, probs = calcProbs(maxN=100, logScale=False, interp=True)


fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

for prob, benford in zip(probs, [0.301, 0.176, 0.125, 0.097, 0.079, 0.067, 0.085, 0.051, 0.046]):
  line = ax.plot(Ns, prob)
  ax.plot(Ns, [benford for _ in Ns], ls="--", color=line[0]._color)


#ax.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

Though i suspect it might be a system / installation dependant problem.

Comment: Can you provide some code which replicates this?

Comment: am doing so right now.

Comment: Yup, looks system dependent - using Anaconda 2.0 on Windows 7 64-bit, I can't reproduce this.